# How to access files outside the document root, or outside the document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, document-library, url, url-rewriting

This is probably a v. dumb question but I'm new and I'm trying to understand if something is possible: I would like to link to files which are outside the sharepoint document root. Is it possible to do so by changing the syntax of what I write in the "URL" box - see image?

Currently, in the URL box I'm putting //myServer1/Data/shareFolder.

But the link that gets applied is https://intranet.my.org/projects///myServer1/Data/shareFolder which definitely does not work.

UPDATE:
These hyperlinks are presented on an EDMS "intranet" with webpages for different groups within our organization. The reason I want to link to folders outside of sharepoint/EDMS is because some files are spatial GIS format files (which we don't store on the sharepoint).

[image]

If this is possible but by other means (i.e. not via the URL input as per above) or if I'm using the wrong language, I would appreciate any relevant links.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, but putting files from let's say googledocs defies the Whole point of SharePoint. Also you need to deal with the permissions in the other native source.

I believe you have more luck creating the hyperlink from scratch via the navigation in SITE SETTINGS - navigation, if as i seem to understand that screen is from the quick launch

Comment: That's where I went - however there is still a root (https://intranet.my.org/projects/) that gets prefixed to my link, and I don't know where to remove that root.

Comment: If you use the 'heading' type of link yes, if you use the 'link' type of link, you can add google,com